# Securing spring mvc REST api using siteminder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, siteminder

I have written REST web service in java using spring MVC. As this service is stateless, how I can secure it using siteminder? For login authentication, we are using siteminder at frontend.

Answer (score 2):

You can protect the web services URLs with CA SSO (aka SiteMinder) the same way you protect the user-facing parts of your website. Just create realms/rules/policies for the URLs. But there are some caveats/tricks:

1. Include the SM session cookie in the client request
2. Remember if the cookie is flagged HttpOnly, it won't work
3. Use BASIC authentication for the realms - this way, your clients will receive a 401 if they aren't authenticated/authorized
4. Also be wary of CORS restrictions if     your web services aren't on the same hostname as the main page(s) of your app

HTH!